# EMF - Limit Selections in Editor

Tags: emf

I've been googling my ass off with little success. I am using EMF to display a Model. I am trying to customize the Propertiesview for certain Elements. I want to filter the options, that it shows inside a dropdown box for a certain attribute. It seems like this is somehow connected to the addBehaviorPropertyDescriptor() function within the respective ItemProvider, but i am not sure what to do now :-/

I hope this rambling is even remotly comprehensable...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out :-) Returning a CustomItemPropertyDescriptor in the addBehaviorPropertyDescriptor() function and overriding the getComboBoxObjects(Object object) did the trick.